# Changing the action buttons on a notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have a notification that I'm trying to update by reusing the same Notification Builder, but there's no way to clear the buttons, you can only call `addAction`. Not using the same Builder results in the notification flashing, which is undesirable. Are there any solutions to this? I'm using `NotificationCompat` from the v4 support library.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for this, any progress on your problem?

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more information? What exactly are you trying to do, what have you done?

Answer (score 7):

```
notificationBuilder.mActions.clear();
```

It's actually `public ArrayList<Action>`, so you can do whataver you want with it.

Comment: It doesn't work for me:( I get an error: "mActions can only be accessed from within the same library group (group=com.android.support)"

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to achieve that:

1. Use a custom layout (just copy the design of the native notification if you want to) and then use this in a RemoteView and just make views visible or hide them. With `remoteView.setViewVisibility(...)` for example... Or change the text of the buttons...
2. Use reflection to clear the builders actions. Would work like following:

   ```
   try {
       //Use reflection to remove all old actions
       Field f = mNotificationBuilder.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActions");
       f.setAccessible(true);
       f.set(mNotificationBuilder, new ArrayList<>());
   } 
   catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {} 
   catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Starting API 24 you can use method `setActions()` and update icon, text and pending intent.

```
Notification.Action.Builder builder = new Notification.Action.Builder( Icon.createWithResource( this, R.drawable.ic_pause) , getString( R.string.pause ), PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 1, new Intent( TIMER_PAUSE ), 0 ) );
Notification.Action action = builder.build();
...
notification_builder.setActions( action );
Notification notification = notification_builder.build();
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
nm.notify( 1, notification );
```